# increasing the stroke with increases the size of the entire stroke while decreasing does not

Tags: javafx

i'm making a very basic drawing application in java using javafx

i use the following code to draw on the canvas:

```java
 canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {

            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {//draw

                gc.setStroke(brushColour);
                gc.setLineWidth(parent.getBrushSize());
                gc.beginPath();
                gc.lineTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
                gc.stroke();//draws the stroke
            }
});
```

and I change the variable `parent.getBrushSize()` when i scroll up or down.
the problem is that when i increase the brush size while drawing the entire stroke becomes bigger while if i decrease the brush size while drawing it behaves as expected:
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkRSV.png)
as you can see on the left i started drawing from the top with a big brush an made the brush size smaller. on the right side i started drawing on the top with a small brush and made it bigger but by doing so it increased the size of the  whole stroke.

how can i make increasing the stroke size behave in the same way as when making the stroke smaller?

Comment: You redraw the complete path. Drawing narrower lines on top of wider ones is not visible...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it turned out that it redraws the entire stroke as soon as i increase the brush size.
to fixed this I added `gc.beginPath();` so if the stroke increases in size it starts a new stroke but this no longer takes advantage of the `gc.lineTo` since now it just draws spheres so i added a boolean `private boolean biggerStroke = false;` with a setter method to my class and added a if statement around the `gc.beginPath();` like so:

```java
canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {

            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {//draw
                if(biggerStroke){
                    gc.beginPath();
                    smallerStroke = false;
                }               

                gc.setStroke(brushColour);
                gc.setLineWidth(parent.getBrushSize());
                gc.lineTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
                gc.stroke();//draws the stroke
            }
});
```

and i set the `biggerStroke` boolean to true each time I increase the stroke size. this way it only starts a new line each time I increase the brush size.